# Filter WooCommerce admin products list by a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I have written code that filters products by manufacturer. On one website this code works on second not working  ... can you help me with this? After filtorvani  products website take one product even though the manufacturer has 158 products.

```
function filter_by_manufacture() {
    $params = array(
        'name' => 'vyrobca',
        'show_option_all' => 'Vyberte výrobcu',
        'taxonomy'        => 'vyrobca',
        'show_count'         => 1,
        'value_field'      => 'slug'
    );
    if ( isset($_GET['vyrobca']) )
        $params['selected'] = $_GET['vyrobca'];

    if ( get_post_type() == 'product' ) {
        wp_dropdown_categories( $params );
    } 
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'filter_by_manufacture');
```

I don't understand why the code shouldn't work
[image]

Comment: this problem make plugin "WooCommerce Search by Product SKU" https://sk.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-search-by-product-sku/

Comment: Any chance to get some feed back on the answer please, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some missing parts in your code:

Try the following:

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'admin_products_by_manufacturer_filter_dropdown');
function admin_products_by_manufacturer_filter_dropdown() {
    global $typenow, $pagenow;

    $taxonomy = 'vyrobca'; // The custom taxonomy

    if( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === $typenow && taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
        $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
        $selected      = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) ? $_GET[$taxonomy] : '';

        wp_dropdown_categories( array(
            'show_option_all' => sprintf( __("Zobraziť všetkých %s", "woocommerce"), $info_taxonomy->label ),
            'taxonomy'        => $taxonomy,
            'name'            => $taxonomy,
            'selected'        => $selected,
            'orderby'         => 'name',
            'show_count'      => true,
            'hide_empty'      => true,
        ) );
    }
}

add_action('parse_query', 'admin_products_by_manufacturer_filter_query');
function admin_products_by_manufacturer_filter_query( $query ) {
    global $typenow, $pagenow;

    $taxonomy = 'vyrobca'; // The custom taxonomy

    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === $typenow && taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
        $q_vars = &$query->query_vars;

        if ( isset($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && is_numeric($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && $q_vars[$taxonomy] != 0 ) {
            $term = get_term_by('id', $q_vars[$taxonomy], $taxonomy);
            $q_vars[$taxonomy] = $term->slug;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.